# How to disconnect an application from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

After receiving some user reports I tried to disconnect Editey from Google Drive using the "Manage apps" option.
It seems to work at first sight, but after a few minutes Editey is back in the list of installed applications.
How to disconnect and remove the app from Google Drive completely?

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I tell people to remove my app.  First you need to remove the app from Chrome and then from Google Drive by going to the gear button and "Manage Apps".  Remove it from there too.  Lastly revoke OAuth tokens by going to https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens to revoke access.﻿  There maybe more than one token to revoke.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/1053346?hl=en-GB for removing app from chrome.